# Why to convert SHA1 to base64 before storing?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, hash, sha1

I need to store passwords in my SQL database. Too high security is not needed at the moment, but instead of using MD5 hash with seed, I plan to use SHA1+seed to store my passwords.

Usage would be simply for a web site user login. So when a user logs in, my C# code would concatenate a salt+password, hash it, and then compare against whats stored in the database.

My question is that in SQL server, should I be storing the SHA1 has as-is (40 characters), or after converting them to Base64(28 characters)?

Most of the example of SHA1 hashing I saw online, seem to be finally converting it to Base64, but I am not sure, why or what would be the benefit of storing SHA1 after encoding to Base64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A SHA-1 hash is a 160-bit value; hashing solutions will produce 20 bytes of output, including unprintable characters. Most implementations convert this into a readable format before storage, either to hexadecimal (40 bytes) or to base64 (~28 characters).

There's no reason to convert a hex string to base64 before storage, so if your strings are already in hex, just leave 'em that way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Chris Heald explains some details but it fails to provide a concrete answer on your question.

The whole point of hashing the password in the first place is to make it unquessable, unrecognizable and unreadable. There is no reason then to convert it back to base64 to make it readable again. The reason for many implementations doing so is mostly because of character sets and encodings. When using simple ASCII based character sets, implementations can vary slightly between databases and programming languages, which might result in data loss or modification when storing and retrieving and hence, therefore a special (uncommon) character in 1 character set might not exist in another character set.